# CSS3 Rotation in SVG: Firefox ignores origin

Tags: html, css, svg

Im working with an SVG output from Adobe Illustrator.  It's on a pretty huge scale, but I've brought the problem over into a JSFiddle.

Here is the **[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/07ft4reh/2/)**

```css
.cls-3, .cls-4{
  fill: none;
}

.cls-12, .cls-4 {
  stroke: #85bce6;
}
.cls-4 {
  stroke-width: 17.8918px;
}

.spin {
  animation-duration: 5.0s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;

  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;

  display: inline-block;
}

.spin.right {
  animation-name: spin-right;
}
.spin.fastest {
  animation-duration: 2.0s;
}

@keyframes spin-right {
  0%   { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    transform: rotate(0deg); 
  }
  100% { 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    transform: rotate(360deg); 
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="200" height="200" viewBox="300 100 900 600">
  <g>
    <g class="spin right fastest">
      <circle class="cls-3" cx="763.662" cy="401.0772" r="287.6463" transform="translate(-63.9564 644.1622) rotate(-44.0769)"/>
      <path class="cls-4" d="M997.0074,232.74a286.59,286.59,0,0,1,52.6308,199.8731c-17.44,157.9025-159.5825,271.77-317.485,254.3307a287.6266,287.6266,0,0,1-254.33-317.4848"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The problem here is that the rotation looks and works great in Blink and WebKit enabled browsers.  But when it comes to Mozilla, it seems to either ignore the Origin I set in the css, or goes bonkers with its own predicted origin.

Not quite sure how to fix this one exactly, as my SVG has many elements that need to be rotated of various sizes.

Anyone got any ideas?

---

Additionally, I don't know for anyone else, but when I look at this in MS Edge the rotation just plain doesn't happen. So I'd be happy to know if it does work for any Edge enabled users out there.

Comment: SVG correctly rotates around the viewBox centre in Firefox. Despite your expectations the bug is a Chrome one.

Comment: The viewbox, as in the global stage as opposed to the boundimg box of the element im applying the rule too? Anything i can do to get these two browsers to rotate elements based on their relative center the same way?

Comment: You could ask the chrome developers to fix the bug or rotate round the origin

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Robert's comment (which I'll admit was new to me.) From the [transforms draft spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-origin-property):

*For SVG elements without an associated CSS layout box the horizontal and vertical offset represent an offset from the point of origin of the element’s local coordinate space*.

That means that the transform origin for SVG elements is not calculated relative to the each element's bounding box (like in regular HTML DOM/CSS). You'll probably need a javascript solution.

Comment: Im ok with a js solution, but every js solution i found the only thing going on was getting js (or jquery or angular) to inject css3 rules. Was honestly surprised i couldnt find a function or lib in js that helped me with this problem

Comment: Well a workaround may be to attach a dummy flexbox layout to each SVG element - but I haven't tried it myself.